# React Native command to generate ios and android code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I have started developing a mobile app in React Native but wanted to know is there a way to generate only the android and ios folder.

Because when I run

> react-native run-android

, it generates the latest code for android and generates the apk as well along with installing it on the emulator.

I wish to know the separate steps for each of the step.

Can any one help me identify this?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the project only with Android code use:

```
react-native init MyProject --skip-ios
```

For iOS:

```
react-native init MyProject --skip-android
```